Apache Airflow service start in wrong folder
When I start the following airflow service, it create a new folder in /home/airflow/airflow/ instead of using the configuration from /home/airflow/ and initialize a new DB.
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service
Wants=postgresql.service
[Service]
Environment="PATH=$PATH:/home/airflow/venv/bin:/home/airflow/"
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/airflow/venv/bin/airflow webserver -p 8080
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I also modified the airflow.cfg file and replaced all the airflow/airflow paths with airflow/.
Thank you in advance for your help

As far as I can see, you are missing the AIRFLOW_HOME variable. So the variable is missing and airflow uses the default path. Example:
Environment="AIRFLOW_HOME={FULL_PATH_HERE}"

Hope this helps
